# Recovering from CarrierWave::IntegrityError due to content_type_allowlist, content_type_white_list or extension_white_list or extension_allow_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, uploader

I have a Carrierwave uploader that accepts multiple files and usage is set up in the typical way in the models.

```
mount_uploaders :attached_files, AttachedFileUploader
```

I’d like to make use of the `content_type_allowlist` functionality so I’ve overriden that in the uploader class.

```
def content_type_allowlist
    [
      'image/jpeg',
      'image/gif',
      'image/png',  . . .
```

This works. When a file with a content type on the list is uploaded, a `CarrierWave::IntegrityError` is thrown, which looks like it occurs in the `cache` function.

Where is the optimal way of catching this exception so I can return a message to the view. Out of the box I’m getting a 500 but I’d like to recover and return to the form.   Are folks typically doing this inside the create and update methods in the controllers?

Ideally I’d like to do such a thing in a validator I have for other uploader rules

```
 class AttachedFilesValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
```

But it seems like the exception occurs before that validation gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you have to do is tell the "uploader" to validate the integrity and this will be added as an error on the model, rather than raising an Error

```
mount_uploaders :attached_files, AttachedFileUploader, validate_integrity: true
```

That being said it seems like something else is going on here because that option is turned on by default:

- Default Configuration Options [Here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/1c7bdd2e329a2d24949dc8ac6c177d31e006ac47/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb#L206)
- Uploader Options: [Source](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L55)
- Currently your Error comes from [Here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/content_type_whitelist.rb#L41)
- Validations to handle Errors can be found [Here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/validations/active_model.rb#L48)

Comment: Interesting point, and setting it to `false` does not stop the exception from being thrown

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to `ignore_integrity_errors` that you can pass to `mount`.  It will still add the errors to your ActiveRecord model but will no longer raise an exception.

Here's the code where Carrierwave decides whether to raise or not: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/06579419cc8e4431095f96ea3fa47629181f56e1/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb#L175-L186